# How to solve MissingSchema error in python/ Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-imaging-library

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

search = input("Enter: ")
params = {"q": search}
url = "https://www.bing.com/images/search"

r = requests.get(url, params=params)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
links = soup.findAll("a", {"class": "iusc"})

for item in links:
    img_obs = requests.get(item.attrs["href"])
    # title = item.attr["href"].split("/")[-1]
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(img_obs.content))
    i = 0
    img.save("./scraped_images/" + str(i), img.format)
    i += 1
```

This is giving in error in line :

```
img_obs = requests.get(item.attrs["href"])
```

Error:

```
img_obs = requests.get(item.attrs["href"])
File "...lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
File "...lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
 raise MissingSchema(error)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=oPXhk8d2&id=E9A0D929216D6015BA67A65BF59804AB191E92C3&thid=OIP.oPXhk8d2A4-q6bRKbjZNlwHaE7&mediaurl=https%3a%2f%2fimage.zmenu.com%2fmenupic%2f4253287%2fs_20200327014201133891.jpeg&exph=432&expw=650&q=pizza&simid=608026258096803600&FORM=IRPRST&ck=9C4AE62E0CCC972731F5CEE3AD28561B&selectedIndex=0': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:///images/searchview=detailV2&ccid=oPXhk8d2&id=E9A0D929216D6015BA67A65BF59804AB191E92C3&thid=OIP.oPXhk8d2A4-q6bRKbjZNlwHaE7&mediaurl=https%3a%2f%2fimage.zmenu.com%2fmenupic%2f4253287%2fs_20200327014201133891.jpeg&exph=432&expw=650&q=pizza&simid=608026258096803600&FORM=IRPRST&ck=9C4AE62E0CCC972731F5CEE3AD28561B&selectedIndex=0?
```

How to resolve the error?

Comment: `/images/search?...` is and relative url, you can't search it directly, you need to include the base site, in this case it look like is `"https://www.bing.com"`

Comment: @Copperfield It is included, right? In my code

Comment: you need to include it directly to the `item.attrs["href"]` because is not there and that is the reason of the error, like for example `"https://www.bing.com" + item.attrs["href"]`, you might also want to check first if the link you get from `item.attrs["href"]` include the schema or not before you do that, the schema is the thing before the `://` in the url, like `https` or `http` and/or a valid link, aka not starting with `/` for example...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example how to load the images from bing into `PIL` object:

```py
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

search = input("Enter: ")
params = {"q": search}
url = "https://www.bing.com/images/search"

r = requests.get(url, params=params)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
links = soup.findAll("a", {"class": "iusc"})

for i, item in enumerate(links, 1):
    u = urlparse(item["href"])
    img_link = parse_qs(u.query)["mediaurl"][0]

    # skip bing thumbnail directly to image:
    if "th.bing.com" in img_link:
        u = urlparse(img_link)
        img_link = parse_qs(u.query)["riu"][0]

    try:
        img = Image.open(BytesIO(requests.get(img_link).content))
        print(i, img_link)
        print(img)
    except:
        print(f"{i} Error loading {img_link=}")
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Enter: python

1 https://wallpapershome.com/images/wallpapers/horned-viper-1080x1920-snake-serbia-montenegro-albania-greece-1319.jpg
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=1080x1920 at 0x7FEDDAB1BF40>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2 http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-AJNv_cRFiW4/UQLLnhVfbUI/AAAAAAAANw8/5q0XzNlcpYk/s1600/41_c091fbcb4c1b0c211df399c638311ee5.jpg
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=568x423 at 0x7FEDDAB0AE20>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3 http://cdn.architecturendesign.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/AD-Magnificent-Castles-And-Their-Fascinating-Ancient-Histories-CoverImage.jpg
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=988x519 at 0x7FEDDAAA8DC0>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4 http://www.wallpapersin4k.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Shirdi-Sai-Baba-Wallpapers-High-Resolution-17.jpg
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=236x419 at 0x7FEDDAB1BF40>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5 http://www.exotic-skin.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/alligator-l-61.jpg
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=960x480 at 0x7FEDDA8F2310>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6 http://didoune.fr/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/cover-facebook-originale-3.png
<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=863x350 at 0x7FEDDAB1BFD0>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
7 http://opiateforthemass.es/images/ofuro.jpg
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=1920x2560 at 0x7FEDDA8F2310>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
8 http://japari-library.com/w/images/4/47/KF3_Blue_Whale_(Photo).png
<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=720x1024 at 0x7FEDDAB1BF40>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
9 https://mundotrucos.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/apex-legends-octane-el-diablo-398x468-1.jpg
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=398x468 at 0x7FEDDAAF8D60>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10 Error loading img_link='https://www.derekwinnert.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/1aaamaz1tumblr_m6khm9EXrz1qc548jo1_1280.jpg'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: oh thanks, I will need to understand url_parse library, cool.